# Create e-card from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

I'm trying to build a simple page, where user can create an e-card. So I have textarea and image. When user starts typing in textarea, text appears on image. This is working great. But now I wan't to convert this text and image to one image (e-card). I tried:

- Converting html code to canvas (but span element gets transformed to block, which is not ok)
- Using canvas from beginning (but quality of text and colors is bad and pressing ENTER in textarea gets ignored in canvas)
- Converting html to pdf and then to image (position absolute gets ignored)

Is there any better way to convert that HTML to image?

HTML:

```
<div class="primer-1">
  <div class="slika-1">
    <img src="https://www.prophotoshow.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/Doorway-to-Winter-600x400.jpg">
    <div>
      <span class="besedilo"></span>
    </div>
  </div>    

  <form>
    <div>Text:</div>
    <textarea rows="10" name="besedilo" id="besedilo"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="potrditev" value="Generate image">
  </form>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
function primer_1_generate(){
    $('.primer-1 span.besedilo').removeAttr('style');
    visinaTeksta = $('.primer-1 span.besedilo').height();
    visinaParent = $('.primer-1 .slika-1 div').height();
    //we scale font size to fit parent
    if(visinaTeksta>visinaParent){
        do{
            f_size = $('.primer-1 span.besedilo').css('font-size');
            f_size = f_size.replace('px','');
            l_height = $('.primer-1 span.besedilo').css('line-height');
            l_height = l_height.replace('px','');
            f_size = f_size-1;
            l_height = f_size * 1.5714;
            $('.primer-1 span.besedilo').css({'font-size':f_size+'px','line-height':l_height+'px'});
            visinaTeksta = $('.primer-1 span.besedilo').height();
            visinaParent = $('.primer-1 .slika-1 div').height();
        }
        while (visinaTeksta>visinaParent);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    primer_1_generate();    
    $('.primer-1 textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {                       
        vrednost = $('.primer-1 textarea').val();
        vrednost = vrednost.split(' ').join('&nbsp;');
        vrednost = vrednost.split('\n').join('<br>');
        $('.primer-1 span.besedilo').html(vrednost);
        primer_1_generate();
    });
});
```

Please see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3357Ljxj/14/

Comment: can you show what you tried with html2canvas ? https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: If you can throw a server in the mix, here's a couple of easy solutions: wkhtmltoimage (for any server), puppeteer (for node)

Comment: This is my result with html2canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/3357Ljxj/17/. You can see that span element is converted to block and background disappeared